# Autosys Job holding in different boxes

Tags: autosys

Suppose we have some 400 jobs in different boxes then I want to put on hold the daily running jobs at 9-10 pm pm only?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use WCC or command line?

In WCC you can just use a comma-separated list of jobs to see only the jobs you want. You can filter by status and select the jobs you want to take action on, then select 'change status' to do a sendevent but check off the 'future' box. Set it up so you send an 'on-hold' event at 9pm and again for an 'off-hold' at 10pm.

If you use command line you'll want to do something like below. Do all of your boxes have some naming conventions in common?  If so you can run the command only once using the string that returns your boxes. In the AutoSys instance I work in we use a prefix structure...

To get the list of running jobs:
autorep -J prefix% | [find for windows or egrep for unix] " RU "

... Where you need the spaces between the double quotes and the two-letter status otherwise it would return lines where the item name contains those two characters.

To do a future sendevent use the usual sendevent syntax and just append the switches to indicate the time you want the action taken.

Will this accomplish what you're looking to do?  If not please let us know if you're using windows or Unix as well as any additional information that can help us understand the specifics of your scenario.